# Cannot convert from std::shared_ptr<_Ty> to std::shared_ptr<_Ty>

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I am getting the following error:

> error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>' to 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty> stack\genericstack.h  36  1 Stack

**GenericStack.h**

```
#ifndef _GENERIC_STACK_TROFIMOV_H_
#define _GENERIC_STACK_TROFIMOV_H_

#include <memory>

class GenericStack {
    struct StackNode {
        std::shared_ptr<void> _data; 
        StackNode* _next;
        StackNode(const std::shared_ptr<void>& data, StackNode* next) 
            : _data(data), _next(next) {

        }
    };

    StackNode* _top; 

    GenericStack(const GenericStack&);
    GenericStack& operator=(const GenericStack&);

protected:
    GenericStack();
    ~GenericStack();
    void push(const std::shared_ptr<void>&);
    void pop();
    std::shared_ptr<void>& top();
    bool isEmpty() const;
};

template <class T>
class TStack: private GenericStack {                  
public:
    void push(const std::shared_ptr<T>& p) { GenericStack::push(p); }
    void pop() { GenericStack::pop(); }
    std::shared_ptr<T> top() { return static_cast<std::shared_ptr<T>>(GenericStack::top()); }
    bool empty() const { return GenericStack::isEmpty(); }
};

#endif
```

**GenerickStack.cpp**

```
#include "GenericStack.h"

GenericStack::GenericStack()
    :_top(0) {

};
GenericStack::~GenericStack() {
    while(!isEmpty()) {
        pop();
    }
};

void GenericStack::push(const std::shared_ptr<void>& element) {
    _top = new StackNode(element, _top);
}

std::shared_ptr<void>& GenericStack::top() {
    return _top->_data;
}
void GenericStack::pop() {
    StackNode* t = _top->_next;
    delete _top;
    _top = t;
}

bool GenericStack::isEmpty() const {
    return !_top;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GenericStack.h"

int main() {
    TStack<int> gs;

    std::shared_ptr<int> sh(new int(7));
    gs.push(sh);
    std::cout << *gs.top() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Why am I getting the error?

I would expect the cast to happen successfully, since with raw pointers I always can case from `void*` to the real type pointer.

What I want to do here is to create a stack template. But I am trying to reuse as much code as I can, so that templated classes would not swell too much.

Thank you.

Comment: _"I would expect the cast to happen successfully, since with raw pointers I always can case from void* to the real type pointer."_ Because `std::shared_ptr` preserves type safety, and you try to throw that away. Also mind that _successfully_ only would preserve you from blatant compiler errors, and isn't safe regarding _undefined behavior._

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, is it impossible what I am trying to do?

Comment: _"is it impossible what I am trying to do?"_ Depends on how these types relate to each other.

Comment: Nitpick (not related to your question, but technically important): the use of the identifier `_GENERIC_STACK_TROFIMOV_H_`. It's formally a reserved identifier.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, they are not related, but every time the cast is performed it is guaranteed that previously in place of the `shared_ptr<void>` `shared_ptr<T>` was put.

Comment: @curiousguy, I think the identifier won`t be used anywhere, but thank you, I understand the issue you are pointing out.

Comment: `static_cast` 1) is not an overloadable operator 2) for user defined types: can only do what a "constructor call" can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because `static_cast` requires the types `from` and `to` to be convertible. For `shared_ptr` that will hold only if [c'tor overload 9](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) would participate in overload resolution. But it doesn't, because `void*` is not implicitly convertible to other object pointer types in C++, it needs an explicit `static_cast`.

If you want to convert shared pointers based on `static_casting` the managed pointer types, you need to use [`std::static_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast), that is what it's for.

So after plugging that fix

```
 std::shared_ptr<T> top() { return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(GenericStack::top()); }
```

Your thin template wrapper will build fine.

Comment: Could you, please, help me with another issue in chat?

Comment: @yourbuddy - If you have another issue it may be worth asking another question.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53467462/use-count-becomes-1-when-using-shared-ptr-in-c) it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the list of constructors for `shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr). You are trying to use overload 9, more specifically the template overload with `Y = void` and `T = int`. However, this template overload *doesn't participate in overload resolution*, because `void*` is not **implicitly** convertible to `int*`. In other words, you cannot convert, even explicitly, `shared_ptr<void>` to `shared_ptr<T>` if you cannot implicitly convert `void*` to `T*`.

Why not use a template in the first place (move `GenericStack` functionality into `TStack`), instead of trying to deal with `void*`?

> But I am trying to reuse as much code as I can, so that templated classes would not swell too much.

By "swell", I assume you mean the template solution would generate too many instances? Do you have any reason to believe that it would indeed be too many?