# use_count becomes -1 when using shared_ptr in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, shared-ptr

**GenericStack.h**

```
#ifndef _GENERIC_STACK_TROFIMOV_H_
#define _GENERIC_STACK_TROFIMOV_H_

#include <memory>

class GenericStack {
    struct StackNode {
        std::shared_ptr<void> _data; 
        StackNode* _next;
        StackNode(const std::shared_ptr<void>& p, StackNode* next) 
            : _data(p), _next(next) {

        }
    };
    StackNode* _top; 

    GenericStack(const GenericStack&);
    GenericStack& operator=(const GenericStack&);

protected:
    GenericStack();
    ~GenericStack();
    void push(const std::shared_ptr<void>&);
    void pop();
    std::shared_ptr<void>& top();
    bool isEmpty() const;

public:
    class EmptyError {
        const char* _message;
    public:
        EmptyError(const char* message)
            : _message(message) {

        }
        const char* getMessage() const {
            return _message;
        }
    };
};

template <class T>
class TStack: private GenericStack {                  
public:
    void push(const std::shared_ptr<T>& p) { GenericStack::push(p); }
    void pop() { GenericStack::pop(); }
    std::shared_ptr<T>& top() { return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(GenericStack::top()); }
    bool isEmpty() const { return GenericStack::isEmpty(); }
};

#endif
```

**GenerickStack.cpp**

```
#include "GenericStack.h"

GenericStack::GenericStack()
    : _top(0) {

};
GenericStack::~GenericStack() {
    while(!isEmpty()) {
        pop();
    }
};

void GenericStack::push(const std::shared_ptr<void>& p) {
    _top = new StackNode(p, _top);
}

std::shared_ptr<void>& GenericStack::top() {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        throw EmptyError("No more elements in stack.");
    }
    return _top->_data;
}
void GenericStack::pop() {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        throw EmptyError("No more elements in stack.");
    }

    StackNode* t = _top->_next;
    delete _top;
    _top = t;
}

bool GenericStack::isEmpty() const {
    return !_top;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GenericStack.h"
//#define NDEBUG
#include <assert.h>

void ordinaryUsageVerification() {
    TStack<int> intStack;

    {
        std::shared_ptr<int> sh(new int(7));
        intStack.push(sh);
        intStack.isEmpty();
        assert(!intStack.isEmpty() && sh.use_count() == 2);
    }
    //assert(!intStack.isEmpty() && intStack.top().use_count() == 1);
    std::cout << "intStack.top().use_count(): " << intStack.top().use_count() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "*gs.top(): " << *intStack.top() << std::endl;
    intStack.pop();
    assert(intStack.isEmpty());
}


int main() {
    ordinaryUsageVerification();

    return 0;
}
```

After the following two line in **Main.cpp**:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sh(new int(7));
intStack.push(sh);
```

I am expecting `intStack.top().use_count()` to be equal 2, but it is equal -1.

I am expecting such a behavior because when calling a `push` method I am passing the `shared_ptr` by reference, so the `use_count` should not change. And only in one place in **GenericaStack.h** here:

```
StackNode(const std::shared_ptr<void>& p, StackNode* next) 
            : _data(p), _next(next) {
```

The `use_count` increments by one for `p`.

So, given that before `push` I had `sh.use_count() == 1` and after `intStack.push(sh);` I had `sh.use_count() == 2` I should get `intStack.top().use_count() == 2`, but what I am getting is `intStack.top().use_count() == -1`. Why?

Thank you.

After modifying **GenericStack.h** in this way:

```
#ifndef _GENERIC_STACK_TROFIMOV_H_
#define _GENERIC_STACK_TROFIMOV_H_

#include <memory>

class GenericStack {
    struct StackNode {
        std::shared_ptr<void> _data; 
        StackNode* _next;
        StackNode(std::shared_ptr<void>& p, StackNode* next) 
            : _data(p), _next(next) {

        }
    };
    StackNode* _top; 

    GenericStack(const GenericStack&);
    GenericStack& operator=(const GenericStack&);

protected:
    GenericStack();
    ~GenericStack();
    void push(std::shared_ptr<void>&);
    void pop();
    std::shared_ptr<void>& top();
    bool isEmpty() const;

public:
    class EmptyError {
        const char* _message;
    public:
        EmptyError(const char* message)
            : _message(message) {

        }
        const char* getMessage() const {
            return _message;
        }
    };
};

template <class T>
class TStack: private GenericStack {                  
public:
    void push(std::shared_ptr<T>& p) { 
        GenericStack::push(p); 
    }
    void pop() { GenericStack::pop(); }
    std::shared_ptr<T> top() { return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(GenericStack::top()); }
    bool isEmpty() const { return GenericStack::isEmpty(); }
};

#endif
```

I am getting an error:

> Error  1   error C2664: 'GenericStack::push' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>' to 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty> &'  ...\stack\genericstack.h    47 Stack

It is about this part:

```
void push(std::shared_ptr<T>& p) { 
    GenericStack::push(p); 
}
```

Comment: What possessed you to return a reference here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, please first extract a [mcve]. In particular, there shouldn't be any need to split this into three files!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, please first extract a [mcve]. In particular, there shouldn't be any need to split this into three files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's review the [specification of `std::static_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast): `std::static_pointer_cast`() returns an rvalue, a.k.a. a temporary object.

```
std::shared_ptr<T>& top() { return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(GenericStack::top()); }
```

This returns a reference to a temporary object that gets destroyed by the time this `top()` returns. Undefined behavior. Most modern C++ compilers are generally capable of detecting this common instance of undefined behavior, and your compiler should be barking at you, on this line.

In general, attempts to defeat C++'s type-safety, by casting things back and forth from a `void *` (the apparent underlying purpose of this set of templates) -- that never ends well.

Comment: It's not "defeating type safety". Code that uses this stack will always get back the type they put into it. It doesn't mean the actual stack logic needs to be templated on the type. We use type erasure all the time to make sure only the truly mandatory type information is generic.

Comment: And as for the return type, the only way that lvalue reference can ever bind to an rvalue is in MSVC and its damn extensions. It's worth mentioning that.

Comment: Temporaries do not bind to mutable references, only to `const` references, that's the reason for the push error.